# Angularjs referencing a form in a controller getting html element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a form named "loginForm" that has a controller "loginController" which has the method "login" set as the submit for the form. Inside of the login method in the javascript if I reference the form without referencing it with scope ; so doing "loginForm" instead of "$scope.loginForm"; I am getting a reference to the html element and if I check the window.loginForm I am finding that this is a global variable. I'm trying to figure out how this variable is getting created and placed into the global scope. Please the plnkr link below for an example of what I am referring to.

http://plnkr.co/YY3ls7ele8uNpnhstG3X

### Controller

```
(function(){
  angular.module('testApp',[])
    .controller('loginController',['$scope',function($scope){

      $scope.login = function(){
        console.debug(loginForm); //console shows html element
        console.debug(window.loginForm); //shows html element
      }  
    }]);
  })();
```

Comment: I haven't tried this out, but if you observe the behavior you describe, it's really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `form` then you would need to pass it in fromthe view.

```
<form name="loginForm"  class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="login(loginForm)">
```

and get it in your method:-

```
$scope.login = function(loginForm){
```

Or use `ng-form="formName"` to get the form controller instance as a part of the scope, but there is an issue with 1.2 version of angular where ng-submit does not get trigerred on ng-form.

Comment: I understand how to get the reference to the form from within the method; the issue I'm trying to figure out is why when I reference just loginForm I am getting back the html element. I'm trying to figure out how this global variable is being created.

Comment: In some browsers you can access formName as a part of window. It is a known thing.. But that form is html element.. where as inside the controller you may really want formController

Comment: Also not only that you would see that you can find the elements with id also accessible as a part of window... Is that your question?

Comment: So PSL is right it seems. Create a stub `.html` file with a `<form name="foo" />`. Check `window.foo`. It isn't related to AngularJS.

Comment: I wasn't aware that if I reference the name of a form without doing document.forms.formname that I could still get the form html element

Comment: @ckruszynsky Yes some browsers places named elements as well as a part of global object to make things worse...

Comment: @ckruszynsky Here you go.. It is called named access:- http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#named-access-on-the-window-object

Comment: As PSL pointed out, the same thing happens for `id` attribute. e.g. `<div id="foo" />` results in `window.foo`. If there are duplicates, it returns an array of all elements/forms with id/named "foo".